# Easier way to make booking calendar than hard-coding

Tags: javascript, html, css

Using HTML, CSS and JS, I would like to make a small booking system. How it will work is that the user will click on an input area, a calendar appears, the user selects a date, and it closes.

So far, I've got this(Ik, not much, but it's my first time using JS on my own, so please bear with me):

```js
let status = false;
let change = document.querySelector("#p-id");

document.getElementById("input-id").addEventListener("click", function() {
    status = toggle(status,change);
});

function toggle(status, change) {
    if (status === false) {
          change.style.visibility = "visible";
          document.getElementById("input-id").value = "";
          return true;
      } else if (status === true) {
          change.style.visibility = "hidden";
          document.getElementById("input-id").value = "Date selected by user";
          return false;
      }
}
```

```css
#p-id {
    visibility: hidden;
}

#input-id{
    margin-left: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id = "text">
    <input type="text" id ="input-id" readonly></input>
</div>

<div>
    <p id="p-id"> I'm supposed to be a calendar </p>
</div>
```

To explain what this is: the input field will be empty(at first). The user will press the field, the calendar will pop up (now, a small text), the user selects the date, and it closes, while writing the date in the field.

The calendar needs to be, well, a calendar, where you can change the month it's displaying and be clickable.

Are you aware of an easier way than hard-coding the calendar, making each day a button and making my life a LOT more difficult?

Thank you in advance, and sorry for the weirdly-worded question.

Comment: You're just playing with some input element here, where's all the "calendar" stuff?

Comment: Aren't you just looking for `<input type="date">`?

Comment: @AlonEitan the "calendar" is supposed to appear after the user clicks on the input field, hence the text

Comment: @Roy I wasn't even aware this was a thing, ngl. I guess that's a really nice solution.

Comment: @Roy I just checked and `<input type="date>` isn't supported by safari, which isn't that good, but I'll see what I can do, thanks for pointing out that HTML tag though :D

Answer (score 0):

Following @Roy 's suggestion, the HTML tag `<input type="date">` is a simple and elegant way to do what I was looking for.

To help with the issue of this tag not having Safari support, here's this fiddle link, which resolves this exact issue: http://jsfiddle.net/2AaFk/1/